# "Open Recent" menu empty on Microsoft Office 2019 apps for Mac?

Tags: mac, microsoft-office, macos-mojave, microsoft-office-2019

On my older machine (High Sierra MacBook Pro, MS Office 2011), apps Excel and Word show a list of recently opened files under Menubar / File / Open Recent. The filenames are then followed by "More…" and "Clear Recent".

[image: 2011 screenshot]

On my newer machine (Mojave MacBook Air, MS Office 2019), apps Excel and Word show no filenames here, the apps only show "More…". Recent files do show on the subsequent dialog that follows click of "More…".

[image: 2019 screenshot]

I've been troubleshooting with Microsoft tech support all afternoon about this, trashing library files and even reinstalling Office. No luck yet. Their reps *seem* to agree there should be a list of files there, but they admit they've not a Mojave test machine.

Anyone else have this issue?

Anyone found a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by creating a new macOS administrative user, confirming that Excel's "Open Recent" list worked properly there, migrating my content to the new macOS user, and deleting the first user.

Seems rash, but I found no other option. If you pursue, I recommend signing out of AppleID/iCloud on the old user before deleting it, or its ghost may haunt your other devices.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I also have this problem.  I have had it for a while, so both pre and post Mojave, and haven't figured out a solution yet.

I did also find this:  [same problem](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mac/forum/macoffice2016-macword/word-2016-mac-list-of-recent-document-is-empty/d02e1dee-9bbb-47d2-8017-abdd6befea06)

Comment: Thanks for reminding me. I solved the issue, and I've post how as an answer here.

Comment: In my case, rebooting the computer helped for the moment.  Although, the newest documents that I had been testing with didn't show up, older ones do.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a number greater than 0 in your "Recent Items" system setting (under General Preferences), which is the first thing to check, then it may be this bug I ran into recently: I found that this happens to me immediately after I save a file to a network (as opposed to local) drive. Next time I open the application, the list is empty. If I then open a local file by finding it manually, then close and re-open the application, the list of recent files reappears in the menu.

Answer (score 0):

Note... something you might check. If at any point in the past you've played with TinkerTool, or a similar tool, make sure you haven't set the number of entries in Recent Items menus to something other than "Operating System Default".

In TinkerTool v7.42, this setting is under the General tab, at the bottom of the panel.

I'd thought this was only going to change the automatic display of recent documents when I Command-Clicked an item, such as Preview, in the Dock. I was incorrect, and changing this value fixed the problem.